# Sonarqube + Jenkins : python coverage report => Line out of range after deleting lines in sources

Tags: python, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I am experiencing a very strange error when analyzing a Python project in jenkins with sonarscanner.

In fact, after a commit where a lot of code lines has been removed, I ran a coverage scan (with python module) and when i tried to pass the report to the sonar-scanner binary plugin on to Jenkins, a java exception appeared, told me that « **line XXX is out of range in file YYY** ». Where XXX is part of my deleted line, and YYY is one of my source file.

Is anybody experienced the same behaviour ?

I already tried to remove .sonar cache in jenkins home and .sonarwork in my jenkins pipeline, but no effect...

Thank you in advance for your help !

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the coverage xml format and latest sonar cli version to analysis the XML for metrics notification. We had two choice:

1- Add a blankspace. (at the bottom of the coverage.xml file). This worked for an old pytest tests.

2- In another project, I updated the following packages: pytest, pytest-cov, and coverage, this to the latest version. (Worked like a charm).

One catch here: when updating to the latest pytest version you might find methods that no longer exist for conftest.py. Eg: get_marker which can be substituted by the new get_closest_marker. Or reserved words like "request". For the latest case you can rename the method named request.